# How can I get the same date in SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

Current date: 2018-03-29

In SQLite, `select date('now','-1 month')` returns `2018-03-01`, and `select date('2018-03-30','-1 month')` returns `2018-03-02` and so on and I know why.

In Postgres, the below all return `2018-02-28`:

```
select date('2018-03-28') - interval '1 month'
select date('2018-03-29') - interval '1 month'
select date('2018-03-30') - interval '1 month'
select date('2018-03-31') - interval '1 month'
```

How can I get the same behavior in SQLite?

Comment: [So I learned about a huge headache in regards to dates with SQLite today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485813/is-the-1-month-in-sqlite-datetime-function-broken)

Comment: @Makoto Hahahahaha. Me too!

Comment: @Makoto you and me both. I like how OP glosses over this nightmare with "and I know why". Should say "and I know why and it's stupid"

Comment: `sqlite_fdw` perhaps  - get postgresql to query a local sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same behavior using this workaround as subquery where **n** is number of months.
Calendar.Date is a column with dates for several years.

+**n** month:

```
select Date from Calendar 
where strftime('%Y', Date) = strftime('%Y', 'now') and (strftime('%m', Date) - 0) = (strftime('%m', 'now') + n) and (strftime('%d', Date) = strftime('%d', 'now') or strftime('%d', Date) = strftime('%d', 'now', 'start of month','+(n+1) month', '-1 day'))
limit 1
```

-**n** month:

```
select Date from Calendar 
where strftime('%Y', Date) = strftime('%Y', 'now') and (strftime('%m', Date) - 0) = (strftime('%m', 'now') - n) and (strftime('%d', Date) = strftime('%d', 'now') or strftime('%d', Date) = strftime('%d', 'now', 'start of month','-(n-1) month', '-1 day'))
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly - I don't think you can.  More rather, I don't think you *should*.

SQLite works differently in terms of its date arithemtic; instead of computing the nearest in terms of human months, it [computes by rendering the date strings provided](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

> ...Note that "±NNN months" works by **rendering the original date** into the YYYY-MM-DD format, adding the ±NNN to the MM month value, then normalizing the result. Thus, for example, the data 2001-03-31 modified by '+1 month' initially yields 2001-04-31, but April only has 30 days so the date is normalized to 2001-05-01. A similar effect occurs when the original date is February 29 of a leapyear and the modifier is ±N years where N is not a multiple of four.

This breaks completely rational thought; 1 month from March 31st is April 30th, and a month away from March 31st would be (nearest to) February 28th.  SQLite cheats and gives the rendered and normalized version of this, which is often close enough, but inaccurate.

So ultimately, I don't think you're going to be able to solve this here.  Not with two differing DBMS solutions computing dates in divergent ways.

This has raised the question of why you're using divergent DBMSes to begin with.  A better solution would be geared towards what you're trying to accomplish; if you have tests in SQLite but your production system is in Postgres, you should look to set your tests up in Postgres instead.

Comment: It's not really as clear as that.  What is (Mar 31 - 1 month) + 1 month?  It all really depends on what you're trying to do.  Analogous problems arise with daylight savings time changes.